# Updating Python for use with AWS CLI

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm trying to use AWS CLI S3 within the Terminal (Mac OS X v10.6.8) and after configuring all of the proper credentials when I run basic commands (e.g., `aws s3 ls`) it does not output anything.

When I do a slightly more complicated command (e.g., `aws s3 mb s3://newbucketname`) it outputs: `__init__() keywords must be strings`.

Based on some research I suspected the cause is that Python 2.6.1 is installed by default, so I downloaded v3.3.2, installed it, and used the 'Update Shell Profile.command' feature to set the correct PATH variable.

Now with the new version of Python installed and configured I still get the same results.  The Terminal still appears to be using the old version of Python, despite the $PATH variable pointing to the new version (v3.3.2).

Any help would be greatly appreciated.  I'm guessing that it has to do with the Terminal not using the new version of Python and thus the AWS CLI functionality doesn't work, but there may be a different cause that I'm not aware of.

Thank you!

Comment: First, Python 3.3.2 should not be putting anything named `python` in your PATH, only `python3`. And there's a good reason for that—Python 2.x and Python 3.x are different languages. Second, what's on the PATH doesn't matter unless the `aws` scripts use `env` in their shbang lines (e.g., `#!/usr/bin/env python` rather than `#!/usr/bin/python`).

Comment: Meanwhile, [the homepage](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/) says "Requires Python 2.6 or higher". And 2.6.1 is 2.6 or higher. So… what makes you think that's the problem?

Comment: Finally, how did you install it? If you installed it using `pip` (as recommended), it will be explicitly configured for the corresponding Python version—`pip-2.6` will give you a Python 2.6 `aws`, while `pip-3.3` will give you a Python 3.3 `aws`. In that case, you should be able to just `pip-2.6 uninstall aws` then `pip-3.3 install aws` and you'll be fine.

Comment: Thanks @abarnert.  To your first comment I didn't mean to imply that it had `python` in the PATH (it's actually `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/git/bin:/usr/X11/bin`).

Comment: The point is that if you look at `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/bin:`, there's no program there called `python`, just `python3` (and `python3.3`).

Comment: I used easy_install to install it.  And as for why I think it's Python that's causing it to not work I only suspected that because I saw a few other posts online about users having issues with the same warning I got above (`__init__() keywords must be strings`).  It very well may be caused by something else.  (for what it's worth I have tested the AWS credentials via other means and they seem to have no issues)

Comment: Well, you really, really should use `pip` instead of `easy_install`. For one thing, `easy_install` doesn't have an uninstaller, which will make it hard to get out of the mess you've gotten into. For another, `aws` explicitly recommends using `pip`, and you generally have an easier time finding help if you follow the recommendations.

Comment: OK, so perhaps if I install v2.7.5 that might address the issue?

Comment: No more than installing 3.3 did. You installed `aws` for Python 2.6; you need to install it for 3.3 or 2.7 if you want it to work with those versions. Let me write up an answer to explain.

Comment: And for setting it up with PIP vs. easy_install the [AWS documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-chap-getting-set-up.html#installing-with-easy-install) seemed to indicate that easy_install was possible.  Didn't know about the lack of uninstall abilities, though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you installed `aws` with the `easy_install` that came with Python 2.6, it will be hardcoded to use Python 2.6—its first line will be something like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/python2.6
```

This [shebang line](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_%28Unix%29) means that the script will run with `/usr/bin/python2.6`. Installing Python 3.3 won't change what's at `/usr/bin/python2.6`. It has nothing to do with what's on the `PATH`, or what the first thing called `python` is on the `PATH`. The `PATH` only comes into play if a script uses `/usr/bin/env` on the shebang line. And `/usr/bin/env python2.6` would of course still find Python 2.6. In fact, even `/usr/bin/env python` would still find Python 2.6, because 3.3 doesn't have anything named `python`, just `python3`.

Meanwhile, even if you managed to hack it up to run with Python 3.3 instead (e.g., by changing that first line to `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/bin/python3.3` or `/usr/bin/env python3`), that would just make it break completely. The `aws` script requires the `aws` package to be installed into your site-packages. You've installed them into your 2.6 site-packages, but not your 3.3 site-packages. (On top of that, many packages install different code for Python 2.x vs. 3.x, so the 2.6 script might not work with the 3.3 package even if it were there.)

Anyway, the right way to fix this is to uninstall `aws` from Python 2.6, and re-install it for Python 3.3.

If you'd used `pip` as recommended, this would be trivial:

```
pip-2.6 uninstall awscli
pip-3.3 install awscli
```

Unfortunately, because you used `easy_install` instead, you have to uninstall it manually.

And really, you don't need to uninstall the packages, just the scripts that ended up in `/usr/local/bin` or somewhere else on your `PATH`. I suspect `rm /usr/local/bin/aws*` will take care of that, but be careful—make sure there's nothing else installed there that starts with `aws` but isn't part of the package.

Meanwhile, for the future, install `pip` and use that. For Apple's Python 2.6, use `sudo easy_install pip` to install it. For Python 3.3, follow the instructions at the [`pip`](http://www.pip-installer.org/en/latest/) site.