# AWS CLI on a MAC point to wrong version of Python

Tags: python, homebrew, aws-cli

After Installing AWS CLI using Homebrew on OS X AWS CLI seems to point to the wrong version of Python. I want to use Python3 not Python2. Any ideas on how to force AWS CLI to use Python3?

Config Below:

```
$ python3 --version
Python 3.6.2

$ python --version
Python 2.7.13

$ aws --version
aws-cli/1.11.120 Python/2.7.10 Darwin/16.0.0 botocore/1.5.83
```

Note the incorrect version of Python.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Updating Python for use with AWS CLI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18705549/updating-python-for-use-with-aws-cli)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Note

By default, the install script runs under the system default version of Python. If you have installed an alternative version of Python and want to use that to install the AWS CLI, run the install script with that version by absolute path to the Python executable. For example:

```
sudo /usr/local/bin/python2.7 awscli-bundle/install -i /usr/local/aws -b /usr/local/bin/aws
```

Install it with bundle, refer to this doc for installation.It worked for me.
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/awscli-install-bundle.html